# How to implement resource server and auth server using spring oauth2 with DB?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

How to implement resource server and auth server using spring oauth2 with DB and how to use the below schema :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql

Test data would be great !!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is nice demo of use Spring OAuth2 with JdbcTokenStore:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/jdbc/src/main/java/demo/Application.java